# Filter files in navigation menu according to modify date in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, cvs

I need to view the java, xhtm.. etc files, in eclipse, according to their modification date and time. How can i do that. (i have to do that within eclipse, you can offer me a plugin.)

Answer (score 1):

`File > Open File` and if you are on a Windows OS on the side of `Look in` click on the dropdown and view `Details`

Comment: thanks for the answer , but i need some kinda filtering mechanism within eclipse. The files that im looking for modified by the Eclipse ide, not all modified files.

Comment: to see the local history of a resource, you can right click on the file found on the Package Explorer you are interested to look at > Compare with > Local History.